# unicode-math symbols not appearing (Luatex)

Tags: luatex, unicode, unicode-math

As the title states, Unicode characters do not appear in math-mode. From my understanding, the package "unicode-math" should make them appear.

My question is, why don't they appear and how I can get it working.

A minimal working example is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,DIV=15, ngerman, parskip=half]{scrartcl}  % parskip=half or parskip=full

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


%% The AMS-Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex%
  % Lua(La)TeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\else
  %default: pdf(La)TeX
  \usepackage{lmodern} % load vector font
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % font encoding
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding
\fi


\usepackage[stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}


\begin{document}

Latex: \(\hbar\) vs. Unicode: \(ħ\) (Unicode normal: ħ)

Latex: \(\mu\) vs. Unicode: \(µ\) (Unicode normal: µ)

\end{document}
```

Which leads to the following output:

[image: Unicode-Math-Demonstration]

As one can see, the Symbols simply do not appear, when used in Mathmode.
I am using Texlive 2021 and luatex and I can not find any relevant warnings, nor errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong input. The mathematical ℏ is U+210F and not ħ (U+0127). Similar for the mu:  is U+1D707 and not μ (U+03BC)

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

Latex: \(\hbar\) vs. Unicode: \(ℏ\neq ħ\) (Unicode normal: ħ)

Latex: \(\mu\) vs. Unicode: \(\neq µ\) (Unicode normal: µ)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Side remark: unicode-math is not so much about input but about output. So it ensures that `\hbar` adds an ℏ to the PDF (and I could copy it from there).

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! 
Do you by chance have tips on how to find the "right" unicode-characters? And how to typeset them efficiently?

Comment: well it depends on your OS and keyboard what you can type easily. I normally simply use the commands, that is fastest.

Comment: I use Fedora Linux with a standard German keyboard. (I think I will probably remap some keys for the often used symbols, e.g. greek letters...) What I meant to ask with the first question was about some kind of list of symbols that will be recognized in math mode and these, which will be recognized in textmode. (I assume all of these are suitable for math mode, https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+1D400. As a remark, the math hbar is not U+201F, because that seems to be "Double High-Reversed-9 Quotation Mark" (https://unicodeplus.com/U+201F)).

Comment: I personally would find it ideal, if LaTex recognized, whether a symbol is in math mode or not and compile it to the "correct" pdf-symbol instead of ignoring it.

Comment: if you input an "a" LaTeX can not guess that you mean a "b". But you can make the input active and define it to do something different in math. (I corrected the 201F to 210F).

Comment: How can I make the input active?

Comment: as @wipet says you can use μ to get text mu in text and math italic μ in math. also latex will not silently drop characters you will have `missing character` warnings in the log

Comment: When I use μ this only appears in math mode - not in text mode, which is the same behaviour as . Also, maybe there should be some, but no, there is no `missing character` warning in the log.

Comment: Your code is using lmodern (Latin modern) for text and it has no Greek - the message in the log for `\mu` is: "Missing character: There is no  (U+1D707) in font [lmroman12-regular]:"

Answer (score 8):

There is misunderstanding, because we have characters with similar shapes but different meanings in Unicode table.

```
ħ U+0127  Latin Small Letter H With Stroke
ℏ U+210F  Planck Constant Over Two Pi, \hslash, \let\hbar=\hslash
µ U+00B5  Micro Sign
μ U+03BC  Greek Small Letter Mu        \mu
 U+1D707 Mathematical Italic Small Mu
```

The character ħ (U+0127) is one from alphabet of a real language (like é, č, etc.) and it is not intended for math typesetting. You have used it in math mode, so the result is undefined. `\hbar` is equal to `\hslash` and it is Planck constant over pi, no letter h with stroke.

The character µ (U+00B5) is micro sign (used for units). It is not intended for math typesetting. You have used it in math mode, so the result is undefined. The `\mu` is equal to Greek small letter mu. Unicode math in TeX typically sets the `\mathcode` of this character U+03BC to U+1D707, i.e. this character is printed in italic.

Comment: Yes, there was a misunderstanding, but you explained it well. Thank you!
Interestingly, the "Greek Small Letter Mu" only appears in math mode, not in text mode, so the result is exactly the same as the one of "Mathematical Italic Small Mu".

Comment: The default math font is latinmodern-math.otf, which has the MAS Unicode block in it, and therefore \mu. The text font, lmodern font (lmroman12-regular.otf) is Latin.

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstanding easily arises.

Visual inspection of the font explains how.

A math font, such as TeX Gyre Pagella - Math, contains *all* symbols (bold, italic, etc) as defined for the MAS Unicode block:

[image: MAS 1]

and

[image: MAS 2]

By comparison, a text font, such as TeX Gyre Pagella, would not need the MAS glyphs:

[image: No MAS]

The text font will also have different font files for italic, bold, bold italic, etc. The math font will typically be only one font file (with ~1k bold, italic etc *symbols* in it).

The text font may or may not have Latin and Greek text alphabets in it (TeX Gyre Pagella has both), independent of the MAS, and as regular, italic, bold, etc. Likewise, the math font (TeX Gyre Pagella - Math also has both text Latin and Greek (but as regular only)).

`unicode-math` package joins all this together (via mapping and ranges), and adds ISO formatting on top.

[image: TGP-M]

Consider case2, where the math font is being used in math mode (in blue), and is *also* being used as the text font in text mode (in red): that is, the MAS glyphs appear in both modes.

So where a glyph comes from, and how it displays in text/math mode, depends on multiple interlocking and overlapping factors.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TexGyrePagella}
\setmathfont{TexGyrePagella-Math}[Colour=blue]
\newfontface\fonttgpm{TexGyrePagella-Math}[Colour=red]
\newcommand\tqbf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\newcommand\texta{[Aa] }
\newcommand\textb{\textit{italic} \textbf{bold} \textbf{\textit{bolditalic}} \textsc{Small Caps} }
\newcommand\mas{\texta                       }
\newcommand\mymus{µ - μ -     }


\begin{document}

1a. text font = TexGyrePagella (1550 chars) [r,i,b,bi, no MAS]

\noindent
t $\mapsto$ \tqbf

\noindent
t$_2$ $\mapsto$ \textb

\noindent
t $\mapsto$ \mymus ; m $\mapsto$ $\mymus$

\noindent
m $\mapsto$ \mas

\bigskip
1b. math font = TexGyrePagella-Math (4247 chars) [has MAS]

\noindent
t $\mapsto$ \tqbf

\noindent
t$_2$ $\mapsto$ \textb

\noindent
t $\mapsto$ \mymus ; m $\mapsto$ $\mymus$

\noindent
m $\mapsto$ $\mas$

\bigskip
2. math font used as text font = TexGyrePagella-Math [MAS as text, MAS as math]

{\fonttgpm 

\noindent
t $\mapsto$ \tqbf

\noindent
t$_2$ $\mapsto$ \textb

\noindent
t $\mapsto$ \mymus ; m $\mapsto$ $\mymus$

\noindent
m $\mapsto$ \mas 

\noindent
m$_2$ $\mapsto$ $\mas$ 
}

\end{document}
```